# Docker-Compose multiple networks, make ports available to outside the host

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose

I am currently deploying a docker network with backend and fronend.
All containers are part of a network basic and one container should be accessible from outside the host machine.

When using docker-toolbox on windows, it works fine. I can access all containers with forwarded ports outside the host machine

```
ports:
  - 8080:8080
```

My problem is, that on Redhat 7, I didn't find a solution do make it accessible wihtout manipulating the iptable so far. I can access all containers with mapped ports inside my host machine. But for making them accessible from outside my hostemachine, I need to do: `sysctl net.ipv4.conf.all.forwarding=1
 sudo iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT`

I think there should be an easier way to user docker networks to do this, right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an external setting, which was continously resetting the forwarding. 
It was nothing directly related to Docker(-Compose).